# Difference between os.chmod, os.fchmod and os.lchmod

Tags: python

I want to change file modes with Python.

The os module has three functions that seem functionally equivalent:

- `os.chmod`
- `os.fchmod`
- `os.lchmod`

What are the differences between these three versions?

Answer (score 4):

`chmod` is used to change the file permissions of a file specified by path.

`fchmod` is used to change the file permissions of a file specified by file descriptor.

`lchmod` is similar to chmod() but does not follow symbolic links.

You can read more in the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man2/chmod.2freebsd.html)

Answer (score 2):

All three methods are being used to change the mode of the file.

```
 - chmod: os.chmod(path, mode, *, dir_fd=None, follow_symlinks=True)
```

chmod by default accepts the path and numeric mode and changes the file permissions. By default it follows symlinks and file

---

```
- fchmod: os.fchmod(fd, mode)
```

Instead of path you may pass the open file descriptor.

---

```
- lchmod: os.lchmod(path, mode)
```

This works same as chmod() however the argument follow_symlinks=True changes to follow_symlinks=False. By affecting on the symlink file rather than target.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation `os.fchmod(fd, mode)` is equivalent to `os.chmod(fd, mode)` since Python 3.3 (`fd`: file descriptor,  a non-negative integer, used as an abstract indicator (handle) to access a file or other input/output resource, such as a pipe or network socket).

I suggest you read the BSD man page at https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lchmod to dive into details. E.g. the main difference between `lchmod` and `chmod`: `lchmod` does not follow   symbolic links.